# Swift Combine: Unable to infer complex closure return type error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, combine

I have the following function:

```
func generateIn() -> Future<Int,Never> {
    return Future{ promise in
        promise(.success(Int.random(in: 1...10)))
    }
}
```

and I'm calling that function from this variable:

```
let sub2 = generateIn()
    .map { value in
        print(value)
        return Int(value)
    }
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate
```

[image]

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error or how can fix it?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Your `print` is probably confusing the compiler. You can try `.map({ Int($0) })`. if that doesn't work you can explicitly define the type as per the example below. The swift compiler is smart but pretty stupid too if you add too much stuff in the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do what it asks you to do; tell it what type the closure is.

```
    let sub2 = generateIn()
        .map { (value:Int) -> Int in
            print(value)
            return Int(value)
        }
```